# command not found even when "which" shows its path with sudo

Tags: shell, path, docker-compose, sudo

I'm on Fedora release 25 with zsh 5.2

I am trying to use a command with `sudo`. (In this example, `docker-compose`)

**Problem:**

`which` command shows where it is.

```
$ sudo PATH=$PATH which docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

In spite of that, command not found

```
$ sudo PATH=$PATH docker-compose
sudo: docker-compose: command not found
```

I could make it work by `` sudo `which docker-compose` `` but I want to know why this occurs.

**What I tried:**

I double-quoted `PATH=$PATH` but got the same result.

```
$ sudo "PATH=$PATH" docker-compose
sudo: docker-compose: command not found
```

Comment: You should never need to run `docker-compose` as root. Is your user not a member of the "docker" group?

Comment: I know. But I just want to know why "command not found" occurs even when "which" shows the path

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/local/bin/` is not on root path. Check with

`sudo bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'`

`/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Use absolute path to the command.
Adding /usr/local/bin to root path seems to be [a security risk](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/136990/whats-the-motivation-for-excluing-usr-local-bin-from-roots-path?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Thank for your answer. Knowing about the security risk, how to add `/usr/local/bin` to the root path ?

Comment: Meaning you want to add it anyway?

Comment: Yes. because I am working inside a VM anyway. The risk is limited

Comment: Add `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"` to `/root/.bashrc`or `/root/.profile`, then  run `source /root/<changed file>` to make changes take effect or logout/login.